# Re-size the Kendo chart while Minimize the window of browser?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

In our team project we are using the **KendoUI** controls here issue while minimize the window chart size not decreasing.How to increase/decrease the size of chart while maximize/minimize  the window of browser.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this works to me:

```
<div id="example">
   <div id="chart"></div>
</div>

<script>  
    // Chart Data Source
    var exampleData = [
         { "FromDept": "ACT", "ToDept": "NSW", "Year": 2010, "Total": 101 },
         { "FromDept": "ACT", "ToDept": "NSW", "Year": 2011, "Total": 1001 },
         { "FromDept": "ACT", "ToDept": "NSW", "Year": 2012, "Total": 501 },
         { "FromDept": "ACT", "ToDept": "YNT", "Year": 2010, "Total": 501 }
    ];


    // Function to create Chart
    function createChart() {

        // Creating kendo chart using exampleData
        $("#chart").kendoChart({
            title: {
                text: "Sample"
            },
            dataSource:
            {
                data: exampleData,
            },
            legend: {
                position: "bottom"
            },
            chartArea: {
                background: ""
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "line"
            },
            series: [{
                field: "Total",
            }],
            valueAxis: {
                labels: {
                    format: "${0}"
                }
            },
            categoryAxis: {
                field: "Year"
            },
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                format: "{0}%"
            }
        });
    }

    // Resize the chart whenever window is resized
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $("#chart svg").width(Number($(window).width()));
        $("#chart svg").height(Number($(window).height()));
        $("#chart").data("kendoChart").refresh();
    });

    // Document ready function
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Initialize the chart with a delay to make sure
        // the initial animation is visible
        createChart();

        // Initially
        $("#chart svg").width(Number($(window).width()));
        $("#chart svg").height(Number($(window).height()));
        $("#chart").data("kendoChart").refresh();

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Try this it works to me both height and width.. $(window).resize(function () {
                $("#chart svg").width(Number($(window).width()));
                $("#chart svg").height(Number($(window).height()));
                $("#chart").data("kendoChart").refresh();
            });

Comment: Make sure all necessary kendo files are included in your page.

Answer (score 6):

Try this...

```
$(window).resize(function () {
     $("#chart svg").width(Number($('.k-content').width()));
     $("#chart svg").height(Number($('.k-content').height()));
     $("#chart").data("kendoChart").refresh();
});
```

Comment: You cannot use percentage in the above snippet.. because jQuery height() and width() will give pixel value

Answer (score 5):

You can attach to the resize event of the window and when it changes, reset the width option on the chart.

```
window.onresize = function () {
    var newWidth = window.innerWidth * .9 // 90% of screen width

    var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart"); // get chart widget
    chart.options.chartArea.width = newWidth; // set new width
    chart.redraw(); // redraw the chart
};
```

Comment: Hi ..I tried this one but no changes are applying.The chart width is same no changes are applied to the chart width.

Comment: It might be something with your page then. Here is the above code working in a jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/rally25rs/TPy2j/1/

Comment: I made a change to my code that now calls `.redraw()` instead of `.refresh()` because redraw just does the rendering whereas refresh re-reads the data out of the DataSource, so will be a little slower.

Answer (score 0):

One more point. Also you may want to disable the animation before the redraw and enable it after

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $("#chart").data("kendoChart").options.transitions = false;
    $("#chart").data("kendoChart").refresh();
    $("#chart").data("kendoChart").options.transitions = true;
});
```