# Use Kendo UI switch in a web application

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I am trying to use a Kendo mobile widget - switch in my web application as below:

[image]

```
<input id="btnConvert" type="checkbox" onclick="onChange();" />

 $(document).ready()
    {        
        $("#btnConvert").kendoMobileSwitch({
            onLabel: "UK",
            offLabel: "US"
        });        
    }
    function onChange(e) {
        alert(e.checked);//true of false
    }
```

But its not firing the click event. i tried the onchange event which is also not working.

Also i tried

```
    $('input:checkbox').change(function () {
}
```

but no success...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a `change` handler event in your `switch` definition.

```
$("#btnConvert").kendoMobileSwitch({
    onLabel: "UK",
    offLabel: "US",
    change : function (e) {
        alert("You changed the value");
    }
});
```

See the documentation [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/mobile/switch#events-change).

Comment: Hi OnaBai, many thanks for your answer. I follow many of your answers and your name is very popular StackOverflow...

Comment: I have another unsolved mystery which i posted a few weeks ago : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166750/kendo-ui-chart-not-resizing , i couldnt find a solution to that yet...

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a JSFiddle? Seems to be related with the order on how things happen (first drawing and the sizing the container)